# Stackoverflow in Removing Inline from Paragraph

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, stack-overflow, paragraph

I have added many inlines to a paragraph in `RichTextBox.CaretPosition`.
When I want to remove an inline like this:

```
        var para = _rtb.CaretPosition.Paragraph;

        Inline inlineToRemove = para.Inlines.FirstInline;
        if (inlineToRemove != null)
            para.Inlines.Remove(inlineToRemove);
```

an error occured: `StackOverflow`

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to provide more details about what you're doing.  I tried adding 100000 inlines to a RichTextBox and then removed the first, but I got no stack overflow.  What calls are in showing in the Call Stack window when you hit a stack overflow?  Can you perhaps put together an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: I'm developing a tokenized textbox and for each token add an inline to richtextbox. every inlines has a close button.
when I press close button and going to remove that inline I've received that error.

Comment: I'm afraid we'll need more information than that.  At the very least, we'll need to see some more of your code.  *If we can't reproduce your stack overflow, we can't help you.*

Comment: I had similar exception (Arithmetic underflow or underflow).
Maybe using dispatcher would help:

   para.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
            {               
                Inline inlineToRemove = para.Inlines.FirstInline;
    if (inlineToRemove != null)
    para.Inlines.Remove(inlineToRemove);

            }));

Answer (score 1):

Before

```
para.Inlines.Remove(inlineToRemove);
```

set

```
(inlineToRemove.Child as TokenItem).Content = null;
```

I donot like this, but it work for me